# Hittest for backBarButton Item, UIBarButtonItem

Tags: cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem, hittest

I'm trying to determine when a UIBackButton is pressed in a sublayer of a navigation app. Would HitTest be used for that? I've seen reference to HitTest, but not exactly sure what it is and how to code for it. Any help is muchly appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

No. Hit testing is the (recursive) process by which UIKit determines which view receives touch events. You shouldn't need to participate in it or invoke it.

If you're using a UINavigationController, it will do the right thing to transition between view controllers when the back button is pressed. If an individual view controller needs to know when it is transitioning off-screen, it should override the -viewWillDisappear: and -viewDidDisappear:. See the documentation for those methods for more information.